# Understanding the logic behind Pointers to Pointers and linked lists in C++ (drawing nodes)

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I'm still trying to understand pointers, drawing nodes and everything but I can't seem to understand some things.

For example here is a function that should delete nodes with even values from a list

```
void delete_even()
{
    node **p= &head;

    while (*p)
    {
        if ((*p)->data % 2 == 0)
        {
           node *nextptr=*p;

           *p=(*p)->next;
           delete nextptr;
        }
        else
        {
            p= &(*p)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

So as I understand it. `p` is pointing to the pointer named `head` and `head` is pointing to the first node.

If I write just `p`, I'm talking about the thing that `p` is pointing at, in this case the pointer head `head`
If I write `*p`, I'm talking about the thing that `p` is pointing at and the one more data data dereferencing. In this case, the first node.

Let's say we have a linked list with 4 nodes.
Also `p` is a pointer to a pointer so it should always point to a pointer and not a node. As I understand it.
[1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDtls.png)
Now, `while (*p)` (In English that means: as long as the thing that `p` pointing at and one more data dereferencing )

I look at `*` as levels.
and `*` means return the value stored in the address kept in the pointer variable
If it's just `p` the pointer look at the whatever the pointer points at.
If it's `*p` do the same thing but one more level, so in this case the first node?

Looking at the list we see that the first node is 1. It's not even so we take this part of the if statement:
`p= &(*p)->next;`
In English( Make the thing `p` points at =  to the first node through dereferencing and  and then getting the address of the next member of this value.

A)I'm not sure if `p`= ~to something~ makes the thing `p` is pointing at change it's value
[2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dya2v.png)
That would make both pointers point at the second node. and the head pointer moved, I don't think it's right...
B)             or `p`= ~to something~ makes the pointer `p` point to  something else
[2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZPRR.png)

For this case we are gonna follow the 2.1 approach.
Now that the second node is 2 and it's even.
Make a new pointer named `nextptr`  and make it point to the same thing `*p` is pointing at
`*p` is currently pointing at the `next` pointer and the `next` is pointing to the second node.

Then we make the thing `*p` is pointing at currently which is the `next` data member that contains the address of the second node of the first node and make = to the second node's next (which is the address of the 3rd node).
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwPlV.png)

Are my logic and drawing correct? because that's what I'm trying to understand

Comment: _"...If I write just p, I'm talking about the thing that p is pointing at..."_ nope if you just write `p` then you are taking about the variable `p`.  The statement implies that you have followed the pointer, this is incorrect.

Comment: Did you know pointers are not that important anymore in current C++? And handwriting datastructures is now considered the advanced topic?  C++ has a std::list and `std::remove_if`. E.g. `std::remove_if(list.begin(),list.end(),[](const int data){ return (data & 1) != 0)`.

Comment: Anyway, what I did when I had to understand pointers is just to make drawings of lists. And modify it with pencil and erases. And then every * is then end of an arrow (the thing the pointer points to).  And instead of doing 2 things on one line like : `*p=(*p)->next;` first write some code with an extra line e.g. `node *tmp = p->next; p = tmp;` so you don't need to keep track of operator precedence rules at the same time.

Comment: @BagPulaInEaProgramareNuInteleg a good way to grasp such logic, is to run that code in your debugger, and watch how the variable values change at each line stepped through.

Answer (score 0):

Note - head is a global variable as coded. It could have been passed as a parameter, and the updated value of head returned.

Initially:

```
head = pointer to the first node
node**p = &head : p = ptr to head
```

If the first node value even, then:

```
node *nextptr=*p; : nextptr = ptr to first node 
(*p) = (*p)->next : head = ptr to second node
delete nextptr    : delete first node
```

else if first node value not even

```
 p = &(*p)->next; : p = ptr to (first node.next)
                    so that *p updates first node.next if second node even
                    and head remains pointer to first node
```